# How to make a Median absolute deviation of $N(0, \sigma^2)$ an unbiased estimator of $\sigma$, asymptotically?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, unbiased-estimator, median

I am looking for a derivation of the fact that $\frac{1}{\Phi^{-1}(3/4)}$ is the multiplier needed for the Median Absolute Deviation (MAD) to be an unbiased estimator of $\sigma$ when $x_i\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Recall the MAD is defined as:

$$
\lambda = b\times Median(| X-Median(X)|).
$$

for some $b$ chosen to meet a given criteria, (e.g. often unbiased-ness) the claim is stated in many places (wikipedia and journal articles) but I cannot find a proof.

Comment: Are you satisfied that it is sufficient to show that $\frac{\text{MAD}}{\sigma}$ at the normal is $\Phi^{-1}(3/4)$?

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica yeah that would be equivalent

Answer (score 1):

An outline of why it is the case that $\frac{\text{MAD}}{\sigma}$ at the normal is $\Phi^{-1}(3/4)$ (where here $\text{MAD}$ is the median absolute deviation from the median).

For the normal, the population median is at $\mu$.

Then consider the distribution of $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$. This is just a standard normal. Hence $\frac{|X-\mu|}{\sigma}$ is the absolute value of a standard normal. Its median will be the value $m$ such that the standard normal has half the area between $-m$ and $m$. We already know that half the distribution is between the first and third quartile, so $m$ is the upper quartile.

Consequently in a general normal distribution, the ratio $\frac{\text{MAD}}{\sigma}$ is the upper quartile, $\Phi^{-1}(3/4)$.

Now for the normal (and indeed in other symmetric distributions with finite mean with positive density at the median) the sample median is consistent as an estimator of $\mu$, so $X-\tilde{x}$ will asymptotically go to $X-\mu$, and so in turn asymptotically the median of $|X-\tilde{x}|$ will be the median of $|X-\mu|$.

As a result, to get a consistent estimator of $\sigma$ from the MAD (median absolute deviation from the median) for a random sample from a normal distribution, you divide the MAD by $\Phi^{-1}(3/4)$.